# Willingly introducing a race condition on a 64-bit pointer value

Tags: c++, multithreading, x86, undefined-behavior, race-condition

I have an application object which can receive messages from multiple services running in multiple threads. The message gets dispatched internally by an instance of a dispatcher object *in the threads of the services*. The application can at any time change the current dispatcher. Dispatchers never get destroyed. The services never outlive the application.

Here's an example code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

using Msg = int;

struct Dispatcher
{
    virtual ~Dispatcher() = default;
    virtual void dispatchMessage(Msg msg) = 0;
};

struct DispatcherA : Dispatcher
{
    void dispatchMessage(Msg msg)
    {
        cout << "Thread-safe dispatch of " << msg << " by A" << endl;
    }
};

struct DispatcherB : Dispatcher
{
    void dispatchMessage(Msg msg)
    {
        cout << "Thread-safe dispatch of " << msg << " by B" << endl;
    }
};

struct Application
{
    Application() : curDispatcher(&a) {}
    void sendMessage(Msg msg)
    {
        // race here as this is called (and dereferenced) from many threads
        // and can be changed by the main thread
        curDispatcher->dispatchMessage(msg);
    }

    void changeDispatcher()
    {
        // race her as this is changed but can be dereferenced by many threads
        if (rand() % 2) curDispatcher = &a;
        else curDispatcher = &b;
    }

    atomic_bool running = true;

    Dispatcher* curDispatcher; // race on this
    DispatcherA a;
    DispatcherB b;
};

void service(Application& app, int i) {
    while (app.running) app.sendMessage(i++);
}

int main()
{
    Application app;
    std::thread t1(std::bind(service, std::ref(app), 1));
    std::thread t2(std::bind(service, std::ref(app), 20));

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) 
    {
        app.changeDispatcher();
    }
    app.running = false;

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

I am aware that there is a race condition here. The `curDispatcher` pointer gets accessed by many threads and it can be changed at the same time by the main thread. It can be fixed by making the pointer atomic and explicitly loading it on every `sendMessage` call.

I don't want to pay the price of the atomic loads.

Can something bad happen of this?

Here's what I can think of:

- The value of `curDispatcher` can get cached by a service and it can always call the same one, even if the app has changed the value. I'm ok with that. If I stop being ok with that, I can make it volatile. Newly created services should be ok, anyway.
- If this ever runs on a 32-bit CPU which emulates 64-bit, the writes and reads of the pointer will not be instruction-level atomic and it might lead to invalid pointer values and crashes: I am making sure that this only runs on 64-bit CPUs.
- Destroying dispatchers isn't safe. As I said: I'm never destroying dispatchers.
- ???

Comment: You are in undefined behavior land.  That's not a good place to be.  Pay a little more and move to well defined behavior land instead.

Comment: Why do you think that making it atomic would be more expensive than a non-atomic load that happens to do the right thing? On x86, an atomic load is IIRC the same instruction as a non-atomic load.

Comment: Also, in regards to *If I stop being ok with that, I can make it volatile* please don't do that.  `volatile` is not a thread synchronization primitive and will still give you undefined behavior.

Comment: I'm not using it as synchronization primitive. I'm using it as a "don't cache me" primitive :)

Comment: When the dispatcher is going to change, send a change message to all the services telling them not to access the dispatcher.  When it is known/confirmed that all messages have been received, change the dispatcher, then send another message to all services advising that the change is complete.   This relies on all services responding to the change messages, and actually not accessing the dispatcher.   [Incidentally, creating new dispatchers and never destroying them gives a resource leak - eventually, your program will run out of resources, and have to be terminated anyway].

Comment: @Peter the application can't know of all possible services. Also I have a finite possible number of dispatchers. So eventually I will have instantiated them all, which is ok. They are stateless objects which know how to handle specific sets of messages.

Comment: This is not necessary, [as you can see](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/D7izhG) an atomic load is just a load, it's a seq_std store that has extra cost.

Comment: @Peter though this is a good idea If I want to keep things safe and redistribute the price of atomic loads on every message to more expensive dispatcher changes

Comment: If it’s OK for a service to use a stale dispatcher value indefinitely, just cache it in a local variable in the thread—or just never change it!

Comment: on *x86/x64* all writes and reads pointer `curDispatcher` will be atomic. as result `curDispatcher` always will be point to some valid (if never destroyed) `Dispatcher` object. think on most other cpu - read/write generic register size value will be atomic too

Comment: @harold: The potentially-atomic object is a pointer to a vtable.  So it's not a choice between `call rbx` vs. `call [rbx]`, it's a choice between `call rbx` vs. multiple levels of indirection that have to be redone every iteration.  But that's the OP's fault for using virtual functions instead of just atomic function pointers.

Comment: for the ones doubting that this is an improvement, here's an simple benchmark: https://pastebin.com/280p0b7A the non-atomic version (define SAFE to 0 at the top) is several times faster

Comment: So you're worried about the overhead of an atomic store, but don't care about the most certainly much higher overhead of using virtual calls? You're paying for sequential consistency while you only need acquire/release semantics in your benchmark though afaics.

Comment: Beyond what @Voo said, you're already forcing it to load from that cache line to check a boolean every time anyway.  Maybe just set a function pointer to NULL *as* the flag?  Re: several times faster: that's because you're changing the dispatcher constantly, in a thread that does nothing else.  Of course that creates a big slowdown in the readers, but is totally unrealistic (I hope).  BTW, you realize that it's not just "slow" to notice a change, it's never going to notice in a loop that keeps the pointer in a reg.  Or else it's == atomic if the compiler doesn't hoist the load.

Comment: Does your real use-case have only one member function, or are there multiple virtual functions you want to control from changing one pointer?  You could still remove a level of indirection by having a pointer to a table of functions directly, instead of a pointer to a vtable pointer to a table of functions.  (the implementation mechanism for virtual functions).  But if there's only one function, seriously just use a plain function pointer.

Comment: Ok, thanks everyone. It turns out that yes.. I've made a stupid mistake. This is actually a  prime example of an atomic that can be loaded and stored with `memory_order_relaxed`. In this case, on 64-bit, the code is more or less identical with the one where there are race conditions (as on a 64-bit cpu there are no *actual* race conditions with it: the pointer *is* instruction-level atomic). So with a relaxed memory order the performance between the safe and unsafe code is indistinguishable